# Firebase - prevent authentication based on role

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an application for Android and Web. On Web, only users that are admins can login. I would like to prevent users that are not admin from logging into the web application.

The only I found to make it "work" is to logout the user when I have the information about his role. The problem is that this makes the page flash, because for some seconds the user was authenticated. I'd like to prevent the sign-in, but I only have access to the User object once the login is made. This is my current code:

```
export function login (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).then(checkRole)
}

function checkRole (user) {
  return ref.child(`UserRoles/${user.uid}`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    let isAdmin = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().admin)
    if (!isAdmin) throw new Error('User is not admin')
  }).then(() => user)
}
```

Although this triggers the `catch` block of the promise, the authentication is still done. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Please don't use images for code.  It's far better to copy the code into a formatted code block in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are better of using [custom user claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which you set on the user to define user role.

You would set the custom claims via Admin SDK:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {role: 'admin'}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

You can then enforce access via security rules without having to do any lookup:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.role === 'admin'",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.role === 'admin'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is the key here, the role access has to be enforced server side.

On the client side, you can get the ID token `currentUser.getIdToken()` and base64 decode the payload to check for the role in the claims to update the UI accordingly but that is only aesthetic and cannot be trusted on the client and the access should be enforced server side.

Comment: the problem is that the access to the tables is public (used in mobile app) but in web only admin should be able to see it. How can I prevent the login action instead of denying access to tables? I know you can check this in server-side, but my app is serverless and auth is done only in frontend.

Comment: How can you prevent login before knowing the role of the user? They would need to provide at least an identifier.

Comment: Yeah, what I need to do is login user first to see if he's admin, but when I do that firebase will trigger the onAuth callback and actually login the user. My code above works, but the user is logged for a couple seconds and can see the contents of the app